# ClusterPoint dump and export tools for command-line

Tags: database, shell, command-line, import, clusterpoint

I am using ClusterPoint database and I really like web interface, but for automation I need to import some data from command-line.

Is there a generic tool available which would allow to import arbitrary XML file into my database from UNIX-style operating system? And is there also a dump utility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I talked to people from Clusterpoint I was told that there are no CLI tools. Which is strange. But also opens up doors for some interesting contributions from community (if only there would be one :D ).

Comment: Yes, there are currently no command-line tools. But it is good suggestion for further development plans, and this also doesn't limit users to create themselves such CLI by using C++ API (this is the simplest).